# Jmeter issue regarding login page

Tags: jmeter

Actually i am facing issue regarding login page. I have created the test plan with CSV data config and trying to login into the application. It is showing "view expire exception" and "transaction still exist for current status 0" on the console.

Comment: Have you done Correlation?

Comment: ya i have already correlated....but on console it is showing error.

Comment: It looks like the correlation is not done, or not completely. There is probably some parameter still stuck to the original value. It looks like a JSF application. You should publish more details if you need more help.